# Json Data extraction

Tags: javascript, json

I have a webservice and it returns json data like this..

```
{"d":"{\"RES\":[],\"STAT\":\"FAIL\",\"SID\":\"0\"}"}
```

how i can i read the STAT=FAIL from this. I wrote service in c#.

my script is

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "http://localhost/EMRDMSService/Service.asmx/User_Login",
    data: "{lg:" + JSON.stringify(GetLogDet) + "}",
    // url: "http://localhost/EMRDMSService/Service.asmx/Permission_List",
    // data: "{userid:" + JSON.stringify(GetLogDet) + "}",

    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    dataType: "json",
    success: function (r) {          
        console.log(r.d.STAT);
    }
});
```

But the r.d.STAT is `undefined`?
Can anybody help me with this?

Comment: `{"d":"{\"RES\":[],\"STAT\":\"FAIL\",\"SID\":\"0\"}"}` *is* valid JSON, but not the JSON you want (you should remove the ``\``).

Comment: Is it possible to update the webservice to return correct JSON?

Comment: its not invalid JSON but `"{\"RES\":[],\"STAT\":\"FAIL\",\"SID\":\"0\"}"` is not json is the value of `d`

Comment: its a valid json.. you can check it in http://jsonlint.com/

Comment: @Sivajith - While it is certainly valid JSON, it's not formatted in the way that you're intending. Your code, it appears, is expecting it to be `{"d":{"RES":[],"STAT":"FAIL","SID":"0"}}`, but because of the double quotes around `d`'s value, the data is being interpreted as a String instead of an object.

Comment: As Rodrigo pointed out, the JSON is valid.  However, you can only get to `r.d`, because the value of `r.d` is a string that looks like this: `"{\"RES\":[],\"STAT\":\"FAIL\",\"SID\":\"0\"}"`.  If you want access to `r.d.STAT`, you need to make sure to remove the double queotes around that string and the escape slashes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As said in some of the comments, `{"d":"{\"RES\":[],\"STAT\":\"FAIL\",\"SID\":\"0\"}"}` isn't correct JSON. However, if you can't update the webservice, you could try this in your `success` callback:

```
var d = JSON.parse(r.d);
console.log(d.STAT);
```

**EDIT in response to OP edits** `r.d.STAT` will be undefined because `d` is interpreted as a String, not a Object. That's why you'll have to parse it or update the webservice to remove the quotes around the value of `d`.

Comment: +1: Tested your workaround for the webservice sending not-quite-so-ideal data to be valid and would solve the original problem (tested in Chrome Console)